# MFC CEvent class member function SetEvent , difference with Thread Lock() function?

Tags: winapi, mfc

what i s the difference between SetEvent() and Thread Lock() function? anyone please help me

Comment: which function Thread Lock() function? can you give its exact name?

Comment: I mean CCriticalSection Member functions(Lock(),UnLock())

Answer (score 0):

Events are used when you want to start/continue processing once a certain task is completed i.e. you want to wait until that event occurs. Other threads can inform the waiting thread about the completion of this task using `SetEvent`.

On the other hand, critical section is used when you want only one thread to execute a block of code at a time i.e. you want a set of instructions to be executed by one thread without any other thread changing the state at that time. For example, you are inserting an item into a linked list which involves multiple steps, at that time you don't want another thread to come and try to insert one more object into the list. So you block the other thread until first one finishes using critical sections.

Answer (score 0):

Events can be used for inter-process communication, ie synchronising activity amongst different processes. They are typically used for 'signalling' the occurrence of an activity (e.g. file write has finished). More information on events:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Critical sections can only be used within a process for synchronizing threads and use a basic lock/unlock concept. They are typically used to protect a resource from multi-threaded access (e.g. a variable). They are very cheap (in CPU terms) to use. The inter-process variant is called a Mutex in Windows. More info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx